# AES encryption in Node.js to match expected decryption in Python

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, aes

I have the following Python script for decryption:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

shared_secret = raw_input('Enter crypted_shared_secret: ').strip()
cipher = AES.new(shared_secret.decode('base64'), AES.MODE_ECB)

blob = raw_input('Enter crypted_blob: ').strip()
plain = cipher.decrypt(blob.decode('base64'))

print(plain)
```

I'm trying to generate the values that would produce the original `blob` using that script, using Node. Here is my attempt:

```
const Crypto = require('crypto');

var shared_secret = Crypto.randomBytes(32);
var cipher = Crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ecb', shared_secret);
crypted_blob = cipher.update(blob, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
```

I can only modify the Node.js script, but I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the shared secret key to Base64 only *after* you use it for encryption:

```
var shared_secret = Crypto.randomBytes(32);
var cipher = Crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-ecb', shared_secret, "");
crypted_blob = cipher.update(blob, 'utf8', 'base64') + cipher.final('base64');
// send `shared_secret.toString('base64')`
```

Other problems:

- `crypto.createCipher` assumes the shared secret is a password and not a key, which is why it will use a bad key derivation (OpenSSL-compatible).
- Node.js' crypto module automatically applies PKCS#7 padding (same as PKCS#5 padding), but PyCrypto doesn't apply any padding on its own. So you either need to use the same unpadding in Python or you can disable padding in node.js with `Cipher.setAutoPadding(false);`, but then you will have to provide plaintexts that are a multiple of the block size (16 byte for AES).

---

Security considerations:

- **Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I have cut the RSA code which was working, the AES is the part that doesn't seem to work.

If I open up node and start with `blob = 'Hello world'` and then run the 4 lines of code, I get e.g. `FH1hDHh49uGiWZhNCtg5Dw==` as `crypted_blob`. Then I can run `shared_secret.toString('base64')` and get e.g. `bUQXpYLhZnR+9vKTU8txkRo7O6j7nrks1MJnxI/YIGo=`.

Then I open up Python, enter the latter as `shared_secret` and the former as `blob`, but I still get a scrambled string (wrong decryption).

Comment: Yes, I missed that you've used the wrong method in node.js. See my edit.

Comment: That worked! Will look into replacing ECB with CBC, thanks for the tip!